# Restrict vertex movement to surface

Tags: modeling, geometry, snapping, retopology

I have some messy boolean geometry that I would like to bevel without retopologizing* (similar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178135/bevel-edge-after-boolean-difference)). This requires moving very small or skinny triangular faces to avoid overlapping faces. I've two approaches:

1. Relax vertices adjacent to the boolean cut, excluding vertices created by the boolean cut.
2. Select vertices created by the boolean cut. Scale down. Enable proportional editing. Scale up.

Both approaches deform the mesh, changing the shape. The mesh appears wrinkled like crumpled paper.

**Is it possible to the force or snap vertices to the current surface?**

*No choice. Normally I do knife project, select a vertex not created on an edge, select by similar amount of connecting edges, and dissolve vertices. This generates sufficiently clean(er) geometry for beveling.*

Comment: ...and just derived a solution. Not the best, but it works. I'd accept a more direct answer involving snapping or otherwise restricting vertex movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate the object. Relax the vertices as required. Add and apply a *shrinkwrap* modifier. Problem solved.